# HTML/CSS Images on left and text on the right. Multi- Browser

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Im trying to have a news-bar with images and text along side it. I can get it to work fine with an individual browser, i.e.( Chrome) but if i open it in Firefox it messes up the format. Is there a simple solution to this issue? I don't understand why the code doesn't work on the other broswer??

I've included a link to the code, as i said this doesn't work multi-broswer. I can fiddle with it to make it work with one only.

Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/f4jfj/1/

```css
#newsBar {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #104979), color-stop(100%, #5198d3));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #104979 0%, #5198d3 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #104979 0%, #5198d3 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #104979 0%, #5198d3 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #104979 0%, #5198d3 100%);
  border-top: 1px solid #336699;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px -1px #000;
  border-right: -5px;
  height: 750px;
  width: 350px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 99;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  /* top, right, bottom, left */
}

#newsBar img {
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#newsBar-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#newsBar-titleBox {
  height: 50px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #0c4482;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #092545;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px -1px #000;
  margin: -455px 0 0 900px;
}

#newsBarTitle {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 8px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsBar">
  <img src="website-myhero.png" align="left" name="Ian Thorpe" style="margin: 10px 0 0 10px; margin-right: 5px;" height="80" width="80">
  <div id="newsBar-text" style="margin:7px;"><a href="News.html" class="link">  BREAKING NEWS: Ian Thorpe who recently went under the knife is unlikely, according to offcials, to ever...</a>
  </div>
  <img src="wikimedia.png" align="left" name="Rio 2016" style="margin: 10px 0 0 10px; margin-right:5px;" height="80" width="80">
  <div id="newsBar-text" style="margin: 14px 0 0 10px;"><a href="News.html" class="link"> Rio is to host the 2016 olympics games. The construction of the actual stadium is currently  ...</a>
  </div>
  <img src="media-olympics-au.jpg" align="left" name="Stephanie Rice" style="margin:10px 0 0 10px; margin-right: 5px;" height="80" width="80">
  <div id="newsBar-text" style="margin: -7px 0 0 10px;"><a href="News.html" class="link"> The Austrailian olympian, Stephanie Rice, has decided to hand in the towel this year. The three time olympic champion ...</a>
  </div>
  <img src="swimIreland-ie.jpg" align="left" name="UCD Race To Midnight" style="margin: 10px 0 0 10px; margin-right: 5px;" height="80" width="80">
  <div id="newsBar-text" style="margin: 18px 0 0 10px;"><a href="News.html" class="link">UCD recently hosted a charity swimming event in aid of Marymount university hospital and hospice. The event took place ...</a>
  </div>
  <img src="npr-org.jpg" align="left" name="M.Phelps" style="margin: 10px 0 0 10px; margin-right: 5px;" height="80" width="80">
  <div id="newsBar-text" style="margin: 18px 0 0 10px;"><a href="News.html" class="link">Micheal Phelps has annouced his retirement from the olympics this year, "I am getting older, and I do find it harder to recover." He said...</a>
  </div>
  <div id="newsBar-text" style="margin: 0 0 0 90px; font-size: 19px;">
    <a href="News.html" class="link"><br /><br />Read more news here</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry i was trying to figure out why it was having issues posting it just then

Answer (score 0):

Firstly- move your inline CSS to your stylesheet, there are are few conflicts. Secondly, simply float your images left, add `clear:both` to them so each appears on a new line, then alter a few of the margins whilst giving the text a set width- and voila!

### [Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4jfj/5/)

```css
#newsBar {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #104979), color-stop(100%, #5198d3));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #104979 0%, #5198d3 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #104979 0%, #5198d3 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #104979 0%, #5198d3 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #104979 0%, #5198d3 100%);
  border-top: 1px solid #336699;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px -1px #000;
  border-right: -5px;
  height: 750px;
  width: 350px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 99;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  /* top, right, bottom, left */
}

#newsBar img {
  margin: 10px 5px 0 10px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

#newsBar-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsBar">
  <img src="website-myhero.png" />
  <div id="newsBar-text"><a href="News.html" class="link">  BREAKING NEWS: Ian Thorpe who recently went under the knife is unlikely, according to offcials, to ever...</a>

  </div>
  <img src="website-myhero.png" />
  <div id="newsBar-text"><a href="News.html" class="link"> Rio is to host the 2016 olympics games. The construction of the actual stadium is currently  ...</a>

  </div>
  <img src="website-myhero.png" />
  <div id="newsBar-text"><a href="News.html" class="link"> The Austrailian olympian, Stephanie Rice, has decided to hand in the towel this year. The three time olympic champion ...</a>

  </div>
  <img src="website-myhero.png" />
  <div id="newsBar-text"><a href="News.html" class="link">UCD recently hosted a charity swimming event in aid of Marymount university hospital and hospice. The event took place ...</a>

  </div>
</div>
```